# Write to an Android Cursor

Tags: android, cursor

Android documentation for [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) says

> This interface provides random
>   read-write access to the result set
>   returned by a database query

I could not figure out what API to modify the values using a Cursor. Is it possible to write into a Cursor?

Answer (score 3):

An answer to a similar question asked on Android Beginners forum:

Yes, there is, Craig. Good question. I'll be happy to help. 
You can subclass SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory to return, from its 
newCursor method, a subclass of SQLiteCursor. This factory gets passed 
to the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor so, when you query it, it will 
return Cursors of your new SQLiteCursor subclass type. 
The SQLiteCursor subclass can then expose methods that manage its 
protected mWindow field, which is a CursorWindow. This object has 
putXxx methods to manipulate the data. 
I haven't tried this myself, so if anyone has any tips or hints, 
please post.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way of writing to a cursor! I wonder why it says that..